# In SSRS Matrix report I need to display one more column as last and need to display only on last page,not as a last column of every page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0, msbi

I have created a Matrix report.  In the matrix report I have limited the report columns per page.

For example, I have limited the number of columns per page to 6. I therefore have 12 columns over 2 pages.  I need to insert one more column after 12th column (13, Cost), and to only display this on the second page of the report, not as a last column of every page.

**Note:** I need to add the "Cost" as last column on last page for the column group.

From the image the columns 1,2,3,4 want to display on last page only.

[My report design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K2VY.png)

**Example:**

[Click here to view the report details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6ueq.png)

Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You talk about 12 columns but your report design only shows 8.  I assume column 12 is the one you have listed as '4' in the image?  Are you sure "limiting the number of columns per page to 6" is the right way to do this, especially if you want 7 columns on page 2.  How have you set up the report to limit the number of columns?

Comment: Hey Jonnus, 
MEMCU is as column group in SSRS report, I was created Matrix too. Dynamically MEMCU will display 16 columns and I was limited 7 columns per page. I need to display 1,2,3,4 after 16th column.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you're trying to achieve exactly because usually tables grow vertically, as in rows get added, which could cause your report to grow in pages. Making it extremely difficult to determine what is the last page of your report.

To solve your problem you could simply create a second Tablix which contains only the columns that you wish to display on the last page. And remove those columns from the first Tablix. This will also make it a lot more easier to determine when to add a page-break.

Using expressions (combined with rectangles for example) you could do a lot more grouping and manipulating of the layout. Unfortunately I don't possess enough information and details to give you more accurate advise but you're always welcome to update your question if you need any more assistance.

---

**Update:**

What you're trying to do in point *[2.]* of your comment is simply not possible with the reporter. There is no way to determine on which page you are leave alone the exact position on that page.
The only way I know how to calculate this accurately is by keeping track of the exact row's nummer you're at aswell as the amount of rows that fit on a page. Needless to say that this is an extremely tedious and troublesome, especially if the columns aren't fixed either.

Using the column grouping as you say in point *[3.]* might be possible but have to share the expressions you used for divide the table and the column grouping to be certain. And even then it'll be a complex expression to force this kind of behavior.

However, I believe you could use my first suggestion and change it slightly based on your new description. Instead of creating a new Tablix below, you could place him next to your first table. This new tablix then only needs to have 1 column, the extra column you're trying to add.
If there is enough space on the last page to place this column next to the last column group, then it will be placed exactly where you want it. This of course won't work if you don't have enough horizontal space on your page, then it'll simply get printed on an entire new page.

Comment: Thank you,
I was limited the column groups per page, if I run my report I will get 7 column groups per page, totally I will get 5 pages. I need to display another column on page 5 at the end of column group.

1. If I add those columns on second Tablix whether can I able to display/merge with first Tablix.
2. If I use "Globals!OverallTotalPages" I can able to get total pages, but I can't able to use page functions in report Body.
3. If I get the column group counts I will hide the columns based on the count.
So plz give any Idea to achieve 2 and 3

Comment: Thank you, If you need more info I will email.

Comment: For 3:
=Ceiling(Code.MyFunc(Fields!MEMCU.Value)/7) this is the expression i used. I created the Listbox and I dropped the matrix report inside the List box to limit the columns in the report and I added one function inside the report properties.

Comment: As per you suggestion I added the 2nd Tablix, that is not working as our expectation. On last page the 2nd Tablix display after the 1st Tablix.

Comment: You are certain there is space enough  on the last page for the 2nd tablix? Else this is the expected behavior. Instead of splitting your table based on a  function, why don't you allow the columns to break automatically? You could insert empty columns  in the right places as place holders to force the correct breaking.

Comment: If you in MSDN pls visit below thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/32f28407-e1ca-457e-92fd-d292e32dde4e/limit-no-of-columns-in-ssrs-matrix-report?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: I need to Limit the columns per page, not Page break for Column group. Plz correct me if I am wrong and I was created Matrix report so I think I cant able to create empty columns. Columns will create dynamically.

Comment: The forum post explains a lot. Also note the following: "*Beside this , you can also spread the columns from one matrix into several matrixes. You can first copy one matrix and then paste it into several ones you want. Then set the filter for each column group to make sure that the total columns’ length in one matrix just fit a page’s width.*" Which is kind of what I suggested. If you really wish to use the first approach, could you maybe include accurate screenshots both of the current behavior and the wanted layout?